# ObservableCollection object reference

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the basics of passing data between different views in Xamarin Forms.

I have a Meeting class that holds an observable collection.  In the code behind I have another `ObservableCollection` that is used as the `ItemSource` of a `listview`.  The `ObservableCollection` in the code behind works ok, but when I try to set `myMeeting.MeetingInvitees = _myMeetingInvitees` I get this message:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

In the constructor of the code behind, I have:

```
myMeeting = this.BindingContext as Meeting;
```

Wouldn't this initialize `myMeeting`?  The Topic and Place properties work ok, just not the collection. So when I do:

```
myMeeting.MeetingInvitees = _myMeetingInvitees;
```

Would this not set these to the same address?

I feel like there is something basic I'm not understanding in the Meeting class of setting the properties of `MeetingInvitees`

Thanks if you could point me in the right direction!

Meeting.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<String> meetingInvitees;
private string meetingTopic;
private string meetingPlace;

public ObservableCollection<string> MeetingInvitees
{
    get { return meetingInvitees; }
    set
    {
        meetingInvitees = value;
    }
}
public string MeetingTopic
{
    get { return meetingTopic; }
    set
    {
        meetingTopic = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MeetingTopic");
    }
}
public string MeetingPlace
{
    get { return meetingPlace; }
    set
    {
        meetingPlace = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MeetingPlace");
    }
}
```

Xamarin Code Behind

```
public Meeting myMeeting;
public ObservableCollection<string> _myMeetingInvitees;

public NewMeetingContactsView ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    _myMeetingInvitees = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    myMeeting = this.BindingContext as Meeting;
    listAttendees.ItemsSource = _myMeetingAttendess;
}

async void btnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMeeting.MeetingInvitees = _myMeetingAttendess;
    var nextpage = new NewMeetingOverviewView();
    nextpage.BindingContext = myMeeting;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(nextpage);
}

async void btnCancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
}

void btnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myMeetingAttendess.Add(entryName.Text);
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have initialized your MeetingInvitees observable collection. Your listview tries to bind the property MeetingInvitees, which when accessed returns return meetingInvitees, which is in turn a null value before initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, instead of doing

`_myMeetingInvitees = new ObservableCollection<string>();`

Change it to the following code after initializing your myMeeting object.

```
public NewMeetingContactsView ()
 {
     InitializeComponent ();
     myMeeting = new Meeting();
     myMeeting.MeetingInvites = new ObservableCollection<string>();
     this.BindingContext = myMeeting;
     listAttendees.ItemsSource = myMeeting.MeetingInvites;
 }
```

You don't seem to have your property MeetingInvites initialzed for myMeeting and that's what is throwing the null reference error.

Comment: listAttendess.ItemSource = myMeeting.MeetingInvitees; still causes the System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object